# sql query not calculating correctly, maybe missing a group?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using sqlite and I have a query which almost works. The calculation for the weekly_hours isn't producing the right figure though. I'm trying to calculate how many hours my staff have spent for a particular client over a given date range. The hours are stored in the timesheet_line file in separate fields (mon,tues,wed,thurs,fri,sat,sun) in 1 record. Of course there maybe more than 1 record associated to that customerID, hence the reason I am using Sum to calculate the total. If I don't use the Sum for the weekly hours and only have 1 record in the timesheet_line file, the calculation returns the correct value. The labour_rate calculation is also miscalculating. This one is a strange one as I need to calculation the weekly_hours spent and multiply it by the cost_rate of the staff that was working for the customer. Each staff may have a different cost rate.

```
SELECT c.customerID, c.customer, sum(il.line_price) AS net, sum (tl.mon + tl.tues + tl.wed + tl.thurs + tl.fri + tl.sat + tl.sun) AS weekly_hours, 
sum( (tl.mon + tl.tues + tl.wed + tl.thurs + tl.fri + tl.sat + tl.sun) * s.cost_rate ) AS labour_rate
FROM customer AS c
  LEFT JOIN invoice AS i
  ON c.customerID = i.customerID
  LEFT JOIN invoice_line AS il
  ON i.invoiceID = il.invoiceID
  LEFT JOIN timesheet_line AS tl
  ON c.customerID = tl.customerID
  LEFT JOIN timesheet AS t
  ON tl.timesheetID = t.timesheetID
  LEFT JOIN staff AS s
  ON t.staffID = s.staffID
  LEFT JOIN project AS p
  ON tl.projectID = p.projectID
  WHERE (i.date BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND '2015-12-01') OR
  (tl.customerID = c.customerID AND t.date BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND '2015-12-01')
  GROUP BY c.customerID
  ORDER BY c.customer ASC
```

Comment: If any of the weekday columns contain `NULL` values then the sum will not be correct.

Comment: Ah ok,not all of the fields day fields have a value. I'm gussing i have to put a not Null condition for each day in the where clause?

Comment: Something like [ifnull()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull).

Comment: I put this into the Select statement, but I guess thats not what you mean't as its producing the old result     sum (ifnull(tl.mon,0) + ifnull(tl.tues,0) + ifnull(tl.wed,0) + ifnull(tl.thurs,0) + ifnull(tl.fri,0) + ifnull(tl.sat,0) + ifnull(tl.sun,0) ) AS weekly_hours